# Tainted Canvas - but only on ONE Windows 10 Chrome PC

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

I have sites with multiple Windows 10 PC's.

All work fine - except ONE PC at ONE site.

The failing PC is running the latest version of Chrome ( but I can't see where I find the actual version number in Windows 10. )

The error is...

`'CanvasRenderingContext2D' : The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

The PC in question is restarted Overnight, and has just had Chrome Un-installed & Installed again.

My options at this point seem to be a) Reinstall Windows 10, or b) Buy a new PC.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

### Look out for anything which is intercepting the request

Whatever antivirus you may have could show that this is just down to a virus. But failing that you have to examine the request in detail.

On both machines, side by side:

1. Open up a new empty tab
2. open the dev tools and switch to the network tab
3. Enable "Preserve Log" and "Disable Cache"
4. Navigate through to the page in question.

You will need to take a very close look at the network requests made in both cases. Something might show up which explains the problem.